# Which load balancer supports Master/Slave configuration?

Tags: apache, nginx, load-balancing

I am looking for load balancer for my web application that will support master-slave kind of configuration or algorithm support.

For now I am using apache proxy but with round robin LB method.

I am not sure if apache load balancer has master-slave support or any module?

Here is what I want exactly: Forward all request to one back end server and once the master server is down the slave or other server will act as hot stub.

Please suggest if any open source load balancer I can use w.r.t to my above requirement.

Comment: What do you mean by master/slave? Forward all queries to one backend and when it fails forwars all to the "slave"? Or some URLs to one and some to other?

Comment: Edited my question with some detail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **nginx** with its [Upstream](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html) module.

Example configuration:

```
upstream myBackend {
    server main.example.com:8080;
    server back.example.com:8080 backup;
}

server {
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://myBackend;
    }
}
```

While the first server (`main.example.com`) is up, nginx will use it. When it comes down, it will use the second server. You can read in the linked manual page for various other tuning parameters (for example when to mark server as failed). Nginx supports HTTPS for both incoming connections and also for connections to the proxy backend.

**EDIT:** For Apache it seems to be possible in version 2.4 using the Proxy Balancer. I have not tested this config. For more details see manual for [ProxyPass](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass).

```
ProxyPass "/" "balancer://hotcluster/"
<Proxy "balancer://hotcluster">
    BalancerMember "http://1.2.3.4:8000"
    # The server below is on hot standby
    BalancerMember "http://1.2.3.6:8000" status=+H
</Proxy>
```

Comment: So apache load balancer does not support this kind of configuration?
Also is nginx supports HTTPS?

Comment: It should be possible also in apache (I have updated the answer)

Comment: I want to ask will apache support multiple salve server configuration?

Comment: You mean multiple hot standbys? I guess yes, I didn't find anything in the manual why it shouldn't work.

Comment: Okay... let me try this also